# Injection versus global static class with Angular 2

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I'm creating a project where I need a "constants" class to contain some configuration values. Here is an extract of this class :

```
export class Constants
{
    static Configuration = class
    {
        static CookieName:string = 'etl_language';
    };

    ...

    static View = class
    {
        static Militaries:string = 'militaries';
        static Mutants:string = 'mutants';
        static Objects:string = 'objects';
        static Scientists:string = 'scientists';
    };
}
```

When I'm in a component with Angular 2, I can use that class by importing it :

```
import {Constants} from "../../misc/constants";
```

And then, just reference it :

```
this.cookieName = Constants.Configuration.CookieName;
```

It works pretty well but I have the feeling that I should use the dependency injection engine of Angular 2 to inject a reference to that class in the constructor but it seems a bit overkill. However, I have the feeling that I'm violating the "Angular way" of doing things, so I don't know if I can stick with my solution or if I have to use DI.

Any advice ?

Comment: With DI you can get rid of all of the `static` stuff and inject the same object instance (a singleton) everywhere.

Comment: @MarkRajcok - Re: "With DI you can..."  OP indicates its possible to get rid of `static` and only use DI but wants advice on if they should.  This subjective question is still relevant today for as to why I am responding 5 yrs later :)  There is a lot of info that you can just use DI, or they "Angular way" is to..  But its valid to ask for why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I might suggest doing instead is change your `Constants` classes to have read-only properties and create a `Providers[]` from them like so

```
@Injectable()
public class ConfigurationConstants() {
  private _cookieName:string = 'etl_language';
  ...
  get cookieName():string {
    return this._cookieName;
  }
  ...
}

export var CONSTANTS_PROVIDERS:Provider[] = [
  provide(ConfigurationConstants, {useClass: ConfigurationConstants}),
  provide(ViewConstants, {useClass: ViewConstatns})
];
```

Then you can bootstrap these providers into the top-level injector for your application making them available wherever you might need them.

```
import {CONSTANTS_PROVIDERS} from './constants';

bootstrap(App, [CONSTANTS_PROVIDERS])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Here's a plunk to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/RPjDxoIZ8wLY3DDIdhJF

**Edit 2:** Plunker is back now and I've updated the example

**Edit:** Plunkr is dead right now so I can't update it but in my comment I meant something like this (I haven't tested this but it should work):

```
public class SubConstants() {
  private _someString:string = 'Some String';
  ...
  get someString():string {
    return this._someString;
  }
  ...
}

@Injectable()
public class ConfigurationConstants() {
  private _cookieName:string = 'etl_language';
  private _subConstants:SubConstants = new SubConstants();
  ...
  get cookieName():string {
    return this._cookieName;
  }

  get subConstants():SubConstants {
    return this._subConstants;
  }
  ...
}

// ... this would allow you to then do:
confConstants.subConstants.someString
// assuming you injected ConfigurationConstants as confConstants
```

Again this is more code than your suggestion of the inner classes so it's probably up to which you prefer.

Comment: Beside the "Constants" class, I also have a "Language" class that should follow the same pattern. The issue is that class contains a lot of inner class. Sometimes, you can have a key like "Language.Materials.Metal.Name". Your approach is interesting but the structure of the class would make me write **a lot** of code. Wouldn't it be interesting to mix your approach with mine ? I remove all the "static" of my class but I export it as a class as you did ?

Comment: I meant "I remove all the static from my class but I **inject** it as a class as you did ?"

Comment: Personally I'd avoid the nested classing and use composition to get the nested keys you're looking for. I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: It looks like plunker is dead right now, I'll up date the one I linked as soon as I can.

Comment: Mmmmh, I see. There is indeed more code but I kind of like the structure it brings. I will try something like that. Thanks

Comment: What's with all the export provide stuff?  Can't you just create a standard service and be done?  I'm asking not to be smart, but because that's what I'm going to do unless I should do otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

DI is optional, but it's good for cases where you want to work with an instance of an object. Imports are ok in many cases, but DI decouples your code from the instantiation of the instance. This is beneficial if you are doing automated testing or want your component to be flexible and accept any object with a given signature.

I have some more info about DI here if you are interested:
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.0

Comment: Yeah, this is why I'm looking for a better way to achieve this than the one I'm currently using. The answer of Zyzle seems to be a good start. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

My advice, for what it's worth. Don't ever use dependency injection unless you actually need it to solve a problem.

Use of DI where it isn't needed, or worse, systemic use of DI throughout an entire application just to satisfy some over-demanding framework will result in code that is incomprehensible. (Probably true of any design pattern).

Angular's hierarchical DI seems particularly egregious to me. Once your application gets large enough working out what is resolving a particular dependency and what else that instance is being shared with, will be a conundrum permeating your entire codebase.

Comment: The problem you describe would only emerge in an improperly-architected application. DI enables testability. Without it, you don't have testable code, and you have a much larger maintenance nightmare.  Use of DI for any other purpose is really a misuse of DI.

Comment: You can certainly integration test an application without recourse to DI as integration testing doesn't require you to rearchitect your codebase to support it. So I presume you must be talking about unit testing. My understanding is that it's IOC that facilitates unit testing, not DI specifically. People did use to manage to unit test before DI became the flavour of the month.

Comment: Personally I much prefer to focus on integration testing than unit testing. Unit testing tells you whether your assumptions are being adhered to, integration testing tells you whether your application works.